# Firebase Firestore, how can you update an array nested in a subfield when have to settle the subfield name programmatically?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Stack:

- Firebase Firestore
- TypeScript 4
- React Native 0.63

The idea is to build a follow/unfollow system for a content management system.

For example, the user want to follow the the posts related to the TypeScript language.

We can imagine that:

```
fitlerId1 == 'Language'
item1 == 'TypeScript'
```

The filters items followed by the user are stored in his user document in Firestore:

```
// Collection: users
// Document: userId
{
  name: 'Joe',
  follow: {
    filterId1: [itemId1, itemId2, itemId3]
    filterId3: [itemId4]
    // ...
  },
  scores: { 
    filterId1: {itemId1: 123} 
    // ...
  }
}
```

Fields are not initialized at null. This user don't have a filterId2 field and some don't even have a follow subfield.

What we need to achieve is a toggle-follow function so that:

If item1 is in filter1, we need to remove it.

Else, we need to either :

- add it to the current array
- or create the array if the field (and maybe subfield) does not exists or is empty.

Here is my current code:

```js
    // Un-follow...
    if (fieldValue && Array.isArray(fieldValue) && fieldValue.includes(itemId)) {
      ref.update({ [`follow.${filterId}`]: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(itemId) })
    }
    // Follow
    else {
      ref.set({ follow: { [filterId as string]: [itemId] } }, { merge: true })
    }
```

I'm not really sure that [`follow.${filterId as string}`] is excepted to work like this but if I don't put the [] I get a typescript error.

I'm also not really sure that set-merge will not erase the current array there.

**Edit:** After test I can confirm that it does erase the array. So we'd better differentiate first creation (where we can use set-merge) from field update (where we shall use firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(itemId))